# Define addcomplextype in nusoap wsdl

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, nusoap

I have this function and `$from, $msg, $rcpts` and `$result`  are arrays. How do I register and define addcomplex type for this function in nusoap-wsdl?

`$uname` and `$pass` are strings and I know how to define that in register

```
function enqueue_multi($from, $rcpt_array, $msg, $type = '',$uname ,$pass)
{
  ......
  return $result;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Worked this out once. http://harx.nl/news/2011/1/11/generate-a-wsdl-using-nusoap-in-php

Hope it helps!

Comment: Please, Try not use "link only" answers ... Try to add the "important" part of the text, so the user don't need to go to another site nor have to read another "wall text" to find his solution.